# Unable to draw image on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to make an image editor. My first step in trying this was to paint an uploaded image on a canvas. For some strange reason, it does not work.

Here is my code. When I upload an image I get an error.

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <label>Upload Image: </label>
        <input type="file" onchange="LoadFile(event)">
        <br>
        <img id="Img">
        <br>
        <canvas id="Canvas"></canvas>
        <script>
            Canvas=document.getElementById("Canvas");
            Img=document.getElementById("Img");
            Ctx=Canvas.getContext("2d");
            function LoadFile(event){
                Img.src=URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
                Ctx.drawImage(0,0,Img);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the problem you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error is thrown because you call function **`Ctx.drawImage(0, 0, Img);`** where you're not respect the right order. So, to fix this error your function call needs to specify first the `Img` the context function `Ctx.drawImage(Img, 0, 0)`

[`drawCanvas()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) take first Parameter as

### image

> An element to draw into the context. The specification permits any
> canvas image source, specifically, an HTMLImageElement, an
> SVGImageElement, an HTMLVideoElement, an HTMLCanvasElement, an
> ImageBitmap, an OffscreenCanvas, or a VideoFrame.